# OpenCL-Kernel renders only every 2nd line of an image

Tags: opencv, opencl

My Open-Cl Kernel only renders every second line of a 2d image.
The image is passed as a OpenCV UMat object using the following signature within the ocl-kernel:

```
_kernel void myFunc(__global const ushort* src, int src_step, int src_offset,
                          __global ushort* dst, int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols) {...}
```

My Kernel is called with `kernel.run(2, [image.width, image.height], [16, 16], true)`

Anybody experienced such a problem?

Comment: What's the image resolution? Could there be a confusion between width/height rows/cols?

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible causes:

- The image width is set incorrectly in OpenCL.
- There is an issue with pointer casting. Your image data is 16-bit `ushort*` and maybe OpenCL expects 32-bit `uint*` instead.